# Verilog modules: estimating power consumption before physical design

Tags: power, digital-logic, verilog, cpu

What can a designer do to get an idea of how much power a various module with consume? It seems like there should exist some decent heuristics to go about doing this, else we would have to wait until deeper into the physical design stage.

A basic idea might be some linear combination of regs + gates + wires, like say:

```
P = x*numRegs + y1*numANDgates + y2*numORgates + ... + z*numWires
```

And perhaps the coefficients could come from a standard cell library. Which unfortunately I don't know where to find, for free at least.

Really though, I just want to be able to do back-of-the-napkin calculations to compare similar modules to each other. Any suggestions? 
EDIT - by all means, share any free CAD tools that may help =)

Thanks

Comment: What kind of design? FPGA, ASIC, ...? In general, your technology vendor should give you some kind of tool for this purpose. It will vary strongly from technology to technology. It will also depend strongly on how your module's outputs are connected (fan-out and wire lengths).

Comment: For sure, it's very dependent on the physical design. I would be thinking ASIC mostly. Hopefully there are some decent heuristics I could use for estimates though, even if it's more complex than what I proposed.

Comment: It still needs to come from your vendor. An On Semi ASIC might have totally different calculations from a Lattice Semi ASIC. And each vendor probably has different processes available. 3.3 V process will be different from 1.8 V process, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably estimate static/leakage power consumed using a formula like you have mentioned. The other aspect is the power consumed while switching which would require some sort of stimulus to measure.

I have used power compiler for one of previous my class projects, which requires the switching activity information which is dumped by a simulator.

http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/labs/vlsicad/ece667/links/power/power_compiler_rtl.gif

Answer (score 2):

Use the vendor's spreadsheet as The Photon commented. See [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/products/design_tools/logic_design/xpe.htm) and [Altera](http://www.altera.com/support/devices/estimator/pow-powerplay.jsp) ones.